# Trafodion installation ERROR: Error while running traf_start

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera-manager, bigdata

I am trying to install trafodion on Hortonworks 2.2 virtual machine.The following are the machine configurations.
Hotonwork 2.2 virual machine
HBase version 0.98.
Centos version.

I have tried following steps to install trafodion.
1) I have downloaded 
log4c++ RPM
Trafodion Installer
Trafodion Server

2)mkdir $HOME/trafodion
mkdir $HOME/trafodion/downloads
cd $HOME/trafodion/downloads

3) yum install to install the log4c++ RPM

4)cd $HOME/trafodion/downloads
tar -zxf apache-trafodion-installer-1.3.0-incubating-bin.tar.gz -C $HOME/trafodion

5)cd $HOME/trafodion/installer
cp trafodion_config_default my_config and Edit Configuration File.

6)cd $HOME/trafodion/installer
./trafodion_install --accept_license --config_file my_config

When running installation I obtain following message.

home/trafodion/traf
****INFO: Copying over sqenvcom.sh
***INFO: untarring build file /usr/lib/trafodion/apache-trafodion-1.3.0-incubating-bin/trafodion_server-1.3.0.tgz to home/trafodion/traf
***ERROR: SQ config file cannot be found (home/trafodion/traf/sql/scripts/sqconfig).
***ERROR: Error while running traf_start.
***ERROR: Setup not complete, review logs.
***ERROR: Exiting....

I don't understand why is it saying that. I have defined all configurations in myconfig file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also the discussion on the [Trafodion dev mailing list](http://trafodion.apache.org/mail-lists.html) on Apr. 21. Here is the answer Amanda gave on that list:

> Amanda Moran via trafodion.incubator.apache.org  Apr 22 (4 days ago)
>
> to dev  Hi there Devidas-
>
> If you are on a single node instance SQCONFIG should equal "". This
>   will signal the installer to go grab our standard file located in
>   $SQ_ROOT/sql/scripts.
>
> Thanks!
>
> Amanda